# tcolorbox horizontal align both text and box

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tcolorbox

In the MWE below, the final box (on the right) is shifted down slightly compared to the other boxes.

How can I align boxes, text baselines, and the plus-signs nicely?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\tcbset{nobeforeafter,height=2cm,valign=bottom,box align=base}
\Large
\tcbox{a} + \tcbox{b} + \tcbox{x}=\tcbox{y}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's the cause of the descender of `y` -- the base of the last box is lower than the base of the first three boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to work, but it's not nice.  It aligns both the box and the text, using the baseline.  There's probably redundancy in it too.

```
\tcbset{on line,height=1cm,valign=bottom,box align=base,baseline=3mm}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\tcbox{\raisebox{-2cm}[2cm][2cm]{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because y has a positive depth (like g, j, etc.). A solution is to raise the letter by its depth.

Here I define a `\mytcbox` that does this:

```
\newcommand{\mytcbox}[1]{%
\newbox\mytcBox%
\savebox{\mytcBox}{#1}%
\tcbox{\raisebox{\dp\mytcBox}{\usebox{\mytcBox}}}%
}
```

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\tcbset{nobeforeafter,height=2cm,valign=bottom,box align=base}
\newcommand{\mytcbox}[1]{%
\newbox\mytcBox%
\savebox{\mytcBox}{#1}%
\tcbox{\raisebox{\dp\mytcBox}{\usebox{\mytcBox}}}%
}
\Large
\tcbox{a} + \tcbox{b} + \mytcbox{x} = \mytcbox{y} + \mytcbox{g} - \tcbox{g}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that for letter that have null depth the output is the same, and for the rest, the letter is raised by their depth.

Comment: this aligns the boxes, but not the text.  I want the text and the boxes both aligned, I presume, by increasing the depth of the box.